# setting image src is not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I'm going to get Url Data of selected image and put it into a created image object. I have the Url Data but this `imgOrg.src = imgSrc;` is not working on FireFox. any Idea why?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var reader, imgSrc, imgOrg;
  if (window.FileReader) {

    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(e) {
      imgSrc = e.target.result;
      console.info(imgSrc);
    };
  }

  var avatarInput = document.querySelector('#imageFile');

  avatarInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    console.info(imgOrg);
    imgOrg = {};
    var element = e.target;
    imgSrc = '';

    if (element.value !== '') {

      reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
      setTimeout(function() {
        imgOrg = new Image();
        imgOrg.src = imgSrc;

        console.log("imgOrg.src= " +
          imgOrg.src);
        console.log(imgSrc);
        console.log(imgOrg.width);
        console.log(imgOrg.height);

        var ratio = imgOrg.width / imgOrg.height;
        var fWidth, fHeight;
        if (ratio >= 1) {
          fWidth = 300;
          fHeight = (1 / ratio) * 300;
        }

      }, 1000);
    }
  }, false);
};
```

```html
<input id="imageFile" type="file">
```

Comment: what if readAsDataURL take more time to finish than 100 ms ?

Comment: 100 ms is quite a short timeout in my opinion. Surely on localhost it should load almost instantly, but wouldn't rely on that.

Comment: @Hacketo, I tried even 500 ms but nothing

Comment: is it outputting something in the console ?

Comment: I attached a sample! returns nothing

Comment: yes, but you did not mentioned what os you are using and the version of firefox. It's working for me.

Comment: almost the last version, 33.1.1

Comment: dont know if the original code was working, but this code is working for me on Firefox 34 on MacOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue was: I was trying to get image's width and height before its loading was finished. After creating image object, I put rest of my code into `imgOrg.onload`

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var reader, imgSrc, imgOrg;
  if (window.FileReader) {

    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(e) {
      imgSrc = e.target.result;
      console.info(imgSrc);
    };
  }

  var avatarInput = document.querySelector('#imageFile');

  avatarInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    imgOrg = {};
    var element = e.target;
    imgSrc = '';

    if (element.value !== '') {

      reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
      setTimeout(function() {
        imgOrg = new Image();
        imgOrg.src = imgSrc;
        imgOrg.onload = function() {
          console.log("imgOrg.src= " +
            imgOrg.src);
          console.log(imgSrc);
          console.log(imgOrg.width);
          console.log(imgOrg.height);

          var ratio = imgOrg.width / imgOrg.height;
          var fWidth, fHeight;
          if (ratio >= 1) {
            fWidth = 300;
            fHeight = (1 / ratio) * 300;
          }
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
  }, false);
};
```

```html
<input id="imageFile" type="file">
```